# Runnnig a Java console application from another Java cosole application

Tags: java, runtime

I need to run this command from a Java console application:

```
 /usr/bin/java -Xms512m -Xmx3072m -jar /Users/ivan/Desktop/market/market.jar 500 500 1 1 0.1 true true /Users/ivan/Desktop/market/files/simulationResult/
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
 Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{command}); // command is the string written above
```

I tried many other things, but I didn't get it. Any help?

Btw, I'm using Mac (if it matters).

EDIT: With the code above I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java -Xms512m -Xmx3072m -jar /Users/ivan/Desktop/market/market.jar 500 500 1 1 0.1 true true /Users/ivan/Desktop/market/files/simulationResult/": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:466)
    at SimulationStarter.main(SimulationStarter.java:59)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:53)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:91)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
... 3 more
```

EDIT #2: I'm now sending this instead of the string "command":

```
            String[] commands = new String[]{
                    "/bin/bash", "-c",
                    "\"/usr/bin/java -Xms512m -Xmx3072m -jar " + simulatorPath + " "
                    + var1 + " "
                    + var2 + " "
                    + var3 + " "
                    + var4 + " "
                    + var5 + " "
                    + var6 + " "
                    + var7 + " "
                    + var8 + " "
                    + "\""          
            };
```

But I still get `/bin/bash: /usr/bin/java -Xms512m -Xmx3072m -jar /Users/ivan/Desktop/market/market.jar 500 500 2 1 0.1 true true /Users/ivan/Desktop/market : No such file or directory`.

`child.waitFor()` returns number 127.

Comment: Capture the output/error streams of that process and check the error.  Then come back with the details.

Comment: How do you start a console on the Mac?  You need to start the console with your Process, then pass the java line as a parameter.

Comment: What happens if you change the command to simply be "java"? Will it work then? If so, you are passing the parameters in wrong. If not, then you do not have ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/ on your path.

Comment: @KonstantinNaryshkin shouldn't it still work `/usr/bin/java`?

Comment: Is there a java binary (or a link to it) at /usr/bin/java and is /usr/bin on your $PATH? I do not know about Mac, but on Windows and Linux, you need to manually add the jdk/bin/ directory to the class path.

Comment: @KonstantinNaryshkin yes, it is on $PATH. and yes, /usr/bin/java is ok.

Comment: @Ivan You did not answer my initial question: Does the command "java" work?

Comment: @KonstantinNaryshkin yes, it does.

Answer (score 2):

If command is the above String then

```
new String[]{command}
```

will give you a String array with one item. You should try something like

```
command.split(' ')
```

where command is a String variable containing your above command.

Comment: In fact, you can just pass the command in as a single String - this will be split into tokens internally, which will do the right thing here.

Comment: @MoritzPetersen what's the difference? and how should that array look like?